# Find all records whose association has a nil association in turn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the models below:

```
class Score < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :composition
end

class Composition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :scores
  has_one :invoice, dependent: :destroy
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :composition
end
```

what's the best way to find the **scores**, whose composition has a **`nil`** *invoice*?

I tried:

```
Score.joins(:composition).where(composition: {invoice: nil})
```

```
csn = Composition.includes(:invoice).where(invoices:{id:nil})
Score.where(csn.include? composition)
Score.where(csn.map(&:id).include? composition_id)
```

```
Score.where(Composition.left_outer_joins(:invoice).where(invoices:{id:nil}).includes? composition)
```

all with errors. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** here are the corresponding tables as per `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "compositions", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
  end

  create_table "invoices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "composition_id"
    ...
    t.index ["composition_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_composition_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "scores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "composition_id",                           null: false
    ...
  end
```

Comment: It will be helpful to give answer if you post the schema of tables @simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following query:

```
Score.joins(:composition).includes(composition: : invoice).where(invoices: { id: nil })
```

Comment: is it make any difference with answer given by @John

Comment: This could work, but I'm not sure about the double-querying using both a `joins` and an `includes`. Like there should be a better way regarding performance

Comment: It uses `Left outer join` to exclude compositions have invoice. It should generate query with following pattern: `SELECT "all fields of Score" INNER JOINS compositions ON xxx LEFT OUTER JOINS invoices ON xxx where invoices.id is NULL`. As the model, I think that invoice belongs to composition so that invoices contains composition_id not vice versa so that the query of @Join didn't work.

Comment: This is still the best answer so far. I also just realized that `.includes` [does not actually degrade the performance](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes), and even increases it on a `.join` depepding on the case

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
Score.joins(:composition).where('compositions.invoice_id IS NULL')
```

above should work, Have a good luck!!!

Comment: This throws `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column compositions.invoice_id does not exist`

Comment: please post your schema for `invoice`, `score` and `composition` table

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query,

```
Score.joins(:composition).where('compositions.id NOT IN (?)', Invoice.pluck(:composition_id))
```

If this not work then let me know the columns present in `compositions` and `scores` tables

Comment: It raises `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NOT"
LINE 1: ...cores"."composition_id" WHERE (compositions.id IS NOT IN (54...`.
Thus I edited my question

Comment: Thanks, but it's still somehow not correct. I deleted some invoices (previously all the compositions had an invoice) so to have some `nil` cases, but this query returns a void `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`